# Array Lists, reading in from file and 2 Classes

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm learning arraylists, I'm unsure of how to read in from file and add it to a list as I am much more used to arrays, are they alike?

I'm also getting many errors when I am trying to instantiate the class object 'film' but never mind about it.

How am I able to get load my file method working? To me it looks right I think I just need a strangers pov.

Also getting an error when trying to find the file symbol. If there is any specific readings I should do for array lists could you please link me or explain best you can.

I'm very new to both coding and stack overflow so if you could dumb anything down and please be patient if I don't understand anything thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CinemaDriver {

   film[] Film;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Film = new film[100];
      ArrayList <Film> list = new ArrayList<Film> ();
   }

   public void readFromFile() {
      File f = new file("file.txt");
      Scanner infile = new Scanner(f);
      int x = infile.nextInt();
      for(int i = 0; i < x ; i++) {
         String title = infile.nextLine();
         String genre = infile.nextLine();
         int screenings = infile.nextInt();
         int attendance = infile.nextInt();
         file.nextLine();
         list.add(title,genre,screenings,name);
      }
      infile.close();
   }

   public void displayAll() {
      for (film f : list ){
         System.out.println(f +"/ \n");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is this method in list list.add(title,genre,screenings,name);? Why you need the film array?

You can directory do it using list.

list.add(new Film(title,genere,screenings,name)); I assume.

Comment: Should be `Film[] films` note the lowercase variable names, uppercase objects, and plurals for collections. Otherwise, arraylists are just dynamically growing arrays (literally implemented that way under the hood)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add my film class, its essentially a class that has 2 strings; title, genre and 2 ints screenings and attendance. it has all the getters and setters for this driver class

Comment: As for the file symbol... `new File("file.txt");`... Fix your typos. Use an IDE and the autocomplete features when you're struggling

Comment: can you recommend any IDE's? I've never used one at this point i'm currently coding this on VIM if thats relevant

Comment: IDE doesn't matter, VIM is great. Go step by step and get your names correct. First check if the readFromFile is compiling. remove other code. after it compiles. Use `System.out.println()` to check if you are able to get the required data. you are adding object to list. so you need to initialize it. Comment below if you need any help.

Comment: Hi @Matt , I'm currently working with IntelliJ as IDE, but Eclipse is also fine, you can download IntelliJ from this web:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/?fromMenu

Answer (score 3):

Your ArrayList keeps Film objects as defined here:

```
ArrayList <Film> list = new ArrayList<Film> ();
```

But you are trying to insert several different objects or values (Strings, ints, etc...) instead of a Film object

```
list.add(title,genre,screenings,name);
```

What you should do is something like this:

Option 1:

```
list.add(new Film(title,genre,screenings,name));
```

Option2:

```
Film f = new Film();
f.setTitle(title);
f.setGenre(genre);
f.setScreenings(screenings);
f.setName(name);
list.add(f);
```